# How do I use the ffmpeg CLI to stretch the beginning of an audio stream, using silence, to match the start of the video?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I'm encoding mpd for DashJS using ffmpeg. I'm trying to encode a video that has audio starting 26 seconds after video. When I play it use DashJS, the video refuses to show until the audio starts. What's the best way to stretch the audio to to the beginning of the video using the ffmpeg cli using silence?

I've tried several filters but with no success.

Here's my command:

"ffmpeg" "-i" "static/uploads/tmp.10370ba20dc842f7af87037c8e25e895.mkv" "-c:v" "libx264" "-x264opts" "keyint=25:min-keyint=25:no-scenecut" "-pix_fmt" "yuv420p" "-profile:v" "baseline" "-level" "3" "-coder" "1" "-g" "250" "-c:a" "libfdk_aac" "-b:a" "192k" "-ar" "44100" "-ac" "2" "-map" "0:0" "-map" "0:1" "-map" "0:2" "-map" "0:3" "-metadata" "title=Video" "-f" "dash" "-use_template" "1" "-use_timeline" "1" "-seg_duration" "5" "-init_seg_name" "$RepresentationID$-init.m4s" "-media_seg_name" "$RepresentationID$-$Time$.m4s" "-max_muxing_queue_size" "9999" "-shortest" "-avoid_negative_ts" "make_non_negative" "static/uploads/abea93fe8fe645f291beb6223398e025/index.out"

I tried amixing evalsrc=0 with source 0:1, the stream that starts at 26 seconds but it still starts at 26 seconds.

Comment: Share your full command.

Comment: And see https://superuser.com/questions/579008/add-1-second-of-silence-to-audio-through-ffmpeg

Comment: I updated the post with the command.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to do this. Read the section on first_pts on the aresample page: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-resampler.html

In my case I added `-filter_complex "[0:1] aresample=first_pts=0 [s1]"`